# Как в TextView задать ссылку на лицензионное соглашение?

Tags: android

Здравствуйте. Необходимо в TextView реализовать что то типа "Нажимая кнопку Оплатить, Вы соглашаетесь с правилами". Причем слово "правилами" имеет цвет отличный от основного цвета текста TextView, и является кликабельным, т.е при нажатии на него происходит переход на другую активити.
autoLink не подходит, т.к там только определенные форматы текста могут являться ссылками, да и сам механизм не очень подходит. Прошу вашей помощи.

Comment: вот уже есть [решение](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10246495/7104538) на stackoverflow

Comment: Там используется autoLink, который как я уже говорил не подходит, т.к мне нужно сделать кликабельным кастомный текст, а не номер телефона или адрес сайта.

Comment: Там ссылку делают кликабельной

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Реализовать то, что вам требуется, в точности, можно:

```
SpannableString ss = new SpannableString("Нажимая кнопку Оплатить, Вы соглашаетесь с правилами");
ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View textView) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, AnotherActivity.class));
            }
            @Override
            public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
                super.updateDrawState(ds);
                ds.setUnderlineText(false);
            }
};
ss.setSpan(clickableSpan, 43, 52, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTV);
textView.setText(ss);
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
textView.setHighlightColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

Выглядеть это будет следующим образом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]